# File system in android

Tags: android, android-file

In android device how can I know partitions are available along with the partition size for all partition in my android device by adb command ?

Answer (score 0):

Android's toolbox suite implements the `df` command, though be aware that the space readings for emulated filesystems (most current implementations of External Storage) may be misleading, as they use the same pool of flash blocks as the Internal Storage.  If you want to see what partitions are available rather than which are mounted, read `/proc/partitions` (for example, with `cat`)

Also note that for several versions now, Android has utilized the Linux kernel's capability of per-process mounts, so programs descending from adbd will see different mounts than application code running as a descendant of zygote.

Any piece of code can also read and parse its `/proc/self/mounts` textual pseudo-file to obtain the file systems and then query their properties, as `df` does.

Comment: Can you tell me step by step how can i show it and write this command in mobile samsung ,I read about file system and I don't know how can do this

Comment: If adb is in your path you can do `adb shell df` otherwise you will need to find where the sdk is installed on your development system and do `/path/to/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell df` (or \'s on windows)  Beyond that, SO isn't really a site intended for people to ask others to write code or tutorials, but rather one on which to ask for specific help in figuring out problems in your own efforts.

Comment: I link mobile samsung on laptop and use " adb shell " I have error that is the device is not found ,can u tell me why please??!

Comment: There are numerous questions here on configuring ADB